# Chern character and cycle groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume $X$ connected and regular with an ample line bundle and of finite dimension $\dim{X} = d < \infty$. The Chern character furnishes an isomorphism $ch: K(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \bigoplus_{i=0}^dgr^iK(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}, \sum_ix_i \mapsto \sum_i\exp(c_1(x_i))$ for $x_i \in K(X)$ the classes of line bundles. We have $gr^0K(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}$, $gr^1K(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} = \mathrm{Pic}(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} = CH^1(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$.

This gives by the splitting principle a morphism $K(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \bigoplus_{i=0}^dCH^i(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$. Is $(K(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q})^{(i)} \to CH^i(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ still an isomorphism for $i > 1$? Here, $(K(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q})^{(i)}$ denotes the $k^i$-eigenspace of the $k$-th Adams operator $\psi^k$ (independent of $k > 1$). This corresponds under the Chern character isomorphism $ch$ to $gr^iK(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I don't understand the question, because there are no free $i$'s in sight. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly.